# MongoDB installation with macOS 13 (Ventura) (command line errors)

Tags: mongodb, macos, ios13, macos-ventura

Has anyone with macOS 13 (Ventura) managed to install MongoDB? Getting the following error:

```
==> Installing mongodb-community@5.0 from mongodb/brew
Error: Your Command Line Tools (CLT) does not support macOS 13.
It is either outdated or was modified.
Please update your Command Line Tools (CLT) or delete it if no updates are available.
Update them from Software Update in System Preferences or run:
  softwareupdate --all --install --force

If that doesn't show you any updates, run:
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
  sudo xcode-select --install

Alternatively, manually download them from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/all/.
You should download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.1.
```

Reinstalled the Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.1, but still getting the same error.

I followed the instructions on MongoDB's site: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Ideally I need 5.0 for a project, but I've also tried installing 6.0 and the same error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following steps should fix the issue. I had the same issue.

- Uninstall the existing CLT
  sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
- Download the Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.1 Release Candidate 2 (latest as of writing) from here: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=Command%20Line%20Tools%20for%20Xcode
- Install the downloaded package
- brew upgrade

And then retry installing MongoDB and the installation should pass through.

Comment: Thank you for this. I used this site along with your guidance and managed to fix it (https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/3822#discussioncomment-3965318)